# FROM keyword not found where expected with dual table

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm trying to run the simple anonymous pl/sql, it fails, when I run it as a query, it works fine

```
declare
     c_minute number;
      c_hour number;
begin
     select
          case when (17 - to_char(systimestamp,'HH24')) < 0 then 0 else 17 - to_char(systimestamp,'HH24') end hours into c_hour,
          case when (17 - to_char(systimestamp,'HH24')) < 0 then 0 else 60 - to_char(systimestamp,'MI') end into c_minute
        from dual;
end;
```

**Error**

```
ORA-06550: line 7, column 103:
PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
ORA-06550: line 5, column 6:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax problem.

selecting multiple columns into variables is like this:

```
select col1, col2, col3 into v1, v2, v3 from . . .
```

Try this:

```
declare
     c_minute number;
      c_hour number;
begin
     select
          case when (17 - to_char(systimestamp,'HH24')) < 0 then 0 else 17 - to_char(systimestamp,'HH24') end hours ,
          case when (17 - to_char(systimestamp,'HH24')) < 0 then 0 else 60 - to_char(systimestamp,'MI') end 
          into c_hour,c_minute
        from dual;
end;
```